# playing video player in flutter with API

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, flutter-video-player

good morning all,
I've a problem with playing video in flutter
I'm using this package [video_player: ^2.4.5](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)
but when I open the screen that contain my video it does not work. it gave me a white screen

here's my code

```js
class VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {

  var  controller;
  var youTubVideoPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        widget.initialUrl.toString() ?? 'https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-5s.mp4');
    loadVideoPlayer();
    super.initState();
  }

  loadVideoPlayer() {
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        print(widget.initialUrl);  // this working well
      });
    });
    // from here it doesn't work
    controller.initialize().then((value) {
      print("Load Video Player Initialized 1111");
      setState(() {
        print("Load Video Player Initialized 2222");
      });
    });
  }
```

this is the out put of this snippet

```
I/flutter (17062): https://www.privilegeapps.com/images/materials/1658523313file.mp4
E/flutter (17062): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
```

and below is my log output

```
W/System  (17062): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(17062): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (17062): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(17062): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (17062): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(17062): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (17062): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(17062): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (17062): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(17062): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (17062): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(17062): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (17062): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(17062): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (17062): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(17062): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:640)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:612)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:365)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1009)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:219)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:299)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source:0)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:636)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:533)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:359)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       ... 6 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):   Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:646)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:197)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17062):       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(Consc
```

finally it's my flutter doctor screen

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at C:\Users\sayed\Documents\flutter_windows_2.2.3-stable\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (3 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\sayed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\sayed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.63.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • DRA LX2 (mobile)  • 5LX9K18817915788 • android-arm64  • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows          • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.134
    • Edge (web)        • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.77

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Try the similar code as doc https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

Answer (score 1):

This is because the certificate of `www.privilegeapps.com` is not trusted. You need to add it's certificate to trusted list.
**Android Solution:**

1. Get certificate using [crip](https://github.com/Hakky54/certificate-ripper):   `crip print --url=https://privilegeapps.com --format=pem`
2. Create **cert.pem** in **res/raw**.
   Put the certificate obtained in 1-step in **cert.pem**. It must start with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and end with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.
3. Create **network_security_config.xml** in **res/xml**. Put these configs in it:

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">privilegeapps.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/cert" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

4. Finally add this to Manifest:

```
<application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

This works if you know the domain in advance. If the video links are coming from user, then you can catch `HandshakeException` and temporarily switch off the SSL security on platform level. And switch it back on after user finishes watching the video:

```
    channel.setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
            switch (call.method) {
                case SECURITY_OFF:
                    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(unsafeSSLFactory());
                    result.success(null);
                    break;
                case SECURITY_ON:
                    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(factory);
            }
        });


    private SSLSocketFactory unsafeSSLFactory() {
        return SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getInsecure(5000, null);
    }
```